# Admin language ignored in frontend

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

This is in Drupal 8 still a really weird behavior. 
When using the admin menu / tool bar or any menu really Drupal totally ignores the setup admin language. In frontend every menu is outputted in the content language - so in my case japanese for example...

This makes it so incredible hard for people to handle foreign content as they never can use any admin element in the frontend of the site.

Is there any solution? I already tried to hack the core toolbar menu as I though it was just a bug - content specific language selection instead of admin interface specific - but thats not the case.

Do I have to build my own admin toolbar with just english menu items?
Crazy stuff.

Thanks

Comment: I did quick test and installed Drupal in some language, idk which one, and it looks like [it fails to translate some of the stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOpUF.jpg) in the toolbar. Seems to me that this is a bug or for some reason those words do not have a translation yet.

Comment: hi there. 
My problem is that I cannot stick to the admin language. That some entries are not supported is not really the issue.

Comment: This is a core bug/limitation, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2313309